# How to make a moving turbulence filter with SVG feturbulence?

Tags: svg, svg-animate, svg-filters

As the question says, is there a way to do that? For example, I can make a infinite moving linear gradient:

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fff0c4" stop-opacity="1">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#fff0c4; #92a6ff; #fff0c4" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </stop>

    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#92a6ff" stop-opacity="1">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#92a6ff; #fff0c4; #92a6ff" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </stop>
</linearGradient>
```

But is there a way to make a horizontally moving <feTurbulence> filter?

I can't think of any attributes of feTurbulence I can use with animate to get the desired effect. I was hoping there would be other ways to achieve the effect.

Comment: try changing the first value of the baseFrequency

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76784212/1038015